# Java: defining an array of user-defined struct

Tags: java

I used to write my program codes in C and now moving to Java trying to define a simple struct and create and array of it in the code below, however the run-time exception occurs 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CPoint.main(CPoint.java:19)**
I know i have to allocate memory to my array somewhere, but do not know where. Any help will be appreciated:

```
  public class CPoint {
public int x;
public int y;

public CPoint(int size){

    System.out.println("Constructor1 is called");
}
    public CPoint(){
    System.out.println("Constructor2 is called");
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    CPoint [] p = new CPoint [3];

    p[0].x=90;p[0].y=80;        // this is line 19

    System.out.println(p[0].x);
}
```

}

PS. I would like to allocate memory somewhere in the class CPoint , not in main, if possible I would like to keep the main() code as simple as possible

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate each of the objects in the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    CPoint [] p = new CPoint [3];

    p[0] = new CPoint();
    p[0].x=90;p[0].y=80;

    System.out.println(p[0].x);
}
```

**Edit:** You can wrap array initialisation into a static method in the class - essentially an array factory method:

```
public class CPoint {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public CPoint() { System.out.println("Inside constructor 1"); }

    public static CPoint[] CPointSet(int size) {
        CPoint[] p= new CPoint[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            p[i] = new CPoint();
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CPoint[] p = CPoint.CPointSet(3);
        p[0].x = 90;
        p[0].y = 80;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to allocate memory somewhere in the class CPoint , not in main, if possible I would like to keep the main() code as simple as possible

Comment: @Cgraphics, That's not possible. But you can try inlining the array initialization.

Comment: @Cgraphics what you can do is create a class wrapper around the array - although this is not really a good java practice.  You would create one class passing the number of elements into it - and then in the constructor you would allocate the array and then allocate each element in a loop.  Again, this is not really a good practice in java.

Comment: also to @Moonbeam: Would you please suggest me a better way which would be a better practice. Also, is there anyway to allocate memory for the array p inside the constructor 1? Thanks

Comment: @Cgraphics see my edits: you can create a static method in the class that would take as a parameter the size of array, init the array and then init each element of the array - this way you can have one call from your `main` method and the get a fully initialised set.

Comment: I edited your recent edit, kindly verify to make sure nothing is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Cgraphics: what have you changed?  I don't seem to see any differences

Answer (score 1):

Array `p` contains 3 `null` entries. Initializing an array will not create the objects therein for you. For more information, see [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your objects before your use them.

```
CPoint [] p = new CPoint [3];
p[0] = new CPoint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree to Moonbeam, new CPoint[3] will create an Array object, which in fact **an array of references** (that's different to C), and all three elements refer to '**null**' initially. No memory (for CPoint struct) is allocated util you new some CPoint objects.

You can initialize arrays in this concise way:

```
CPoint[] p = { new CPoint(), new CPoint(), new CPoint() }

p[0].x=90; p[0].y=80;

System.out.println(p[0].x);
```